# How can I assign a value to a variable declared outside the exception in bigquery?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, bigquery-udf

I am using a stored procedure and I need to assign the value to a variable declared outside the exception, the idea is to be able to call another stored procedure with additional variables when an error occurs

```
BEGIN
DECLARE v_error string;
SELECT 1/0; --division by zero: 1 / 0
EXCEPTION WHEN ERROR THEN
SET v_error = CONCAT('execution error: ',@@error.message, ' Query: ',@@error.statement_text);
END;
```

the result is:

```
Undeclared variable: v_error at [5:5]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to bring any value from the main block into the `EXCEPTION` block, then `DECLARE` outside the `BEGIN` block.

```sql
DECLARE kk INT64;

BEGIN
  SET kk = (SELECT MAX(i) FROM `fh-bigquery.public_dump.numbers_255`);
  SELECT 1/0;
EXCEPTION WHEN ERROR THEN
  SELECT kk;
END;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but if I wanted to call another stored procedure sending additional variables that are not calculated within the exception, how could I do it?

Comment: Can you re-calculate them within the exception?

Comment: (I added to the answer that using those declared variables in the exception is not allowed explicitly)

Comment: @gerardoherreras - I completely changed my answer - I think now I got what you want

Comment: Perfect Felipe, that is the solution thanks for your answer